# Check constraint not working in mariaDB

Tags: mariadb, check-constraint

I created a table using the following statement.

```
create table constraint_test(name varchar(20), city varchar(20) not null check (city in ('chennai','vellore')), phone numeric(10));
```

But when I insert as,

```
insert into constraint_test values('abcd,'ooty',123456);
```

it gets stored. How can I restrict it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
city ENUM('chennai', 'vellore')
```

or maybe

```
city ENUM('UNKNOWN', 'chennai', 'vellore')
```

Or you could use a TRIGGER.

Or you could implement the check in your application code.  After all, not everything can be done in SQL.